# Ionic 3 how to cache unfinished form inputs when the page is leaved

Tags: angularjs, caching, ionic-framework, ionic3, formbuilder

Is there a way to cache a unfinished form when the page is leaved? When I go to the form and suddenly I try to put some data on each input field and when I leave that page the input field is cleared.

I used `navCtrl.push` to go to that page where I want to create a **POST**.

I also used `formBuilder` of **Angular forms** to structure my **form model**.

How can I do that?

Appreciate if someone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by creating a **function** in a provider to check and loop through the formBuilder object. If one field has an existing value a alert controller will pop up if the user wants to leave. If not it will proceed to leave the page.

Here is the code below:

in your **page**

```
async ionViewCanLeave() {
    const formObj = this.form.value
    if (!this.done) await this.alertMsg.allowUserToLeaveForm(formObj)
  }
```

in the **provider**

```
allowUserToLeaveForm(formObject) {
    const lengthChecker = formObject
    const vals = Object.keys(lengthChecker).map((key) => lengthChecker[key].length)
    const checkArr = vals.some(field => field > 0)
    if (checkArr) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
          subTitle: 'Are you sure you want to leave the page?',
          title: 'Your changes will not be saved',
          enableBackdropDismiss: false,
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'No',
              handler: () => {
                reject();
              }
            },
            {
              text: 'Yes',
              handler: () => {
                resolve();
              }
            }
          ]
        });
        confirm.present();
      });
    }
  }
```